# android Как не дать процессам activity заснуть?

Tags: android, многопоточность

Есть приложение, которое содержит активность `MainActivity`. Активность занимается сбором *GPS* координат (в фоне) и отправкой их на сервер.

Если запустить приложение и "забыть" про него, то оно какое-то время работает (максимум час), т.е. собирает координаты, и таймеры, запущенные в `onCreate()` работают. Потом приложение висит в открытых, но ничего не делает, лог не пишет.
Если его активизировать, то все снова работает нормально.

Я написал для него таск через `AlarmManager`, чтобы каждую минуту просто выполнялась запись в лог. Создание объекта класса, в котором прописан `alarm` происходит в  перегруженном `onCreate()`.
После этого приложение перестало засыпать. Однако на некоторых устройствах все же через несколько часов может заснуть. При этом `Alarm` пишет лог стабильно.

Я решил отследить жизненный цикл приложения и увидел, что после того, как основная форма становится неактивной, всегда сразу выполняется `OnStop()` и `OnDestroy()`. Т.е. процессы продолжают работать и после `OnDestroy()`. Но потом могут быть усыплены.

---

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как мне периодически активизировать приложение (может, можно как-то инициировать вызов `onCreate()`), чтобы не усыплялись запущенные таймерами процессы.
Спасибо.

Comment: Для работе в фоне есть Service. Активити не подходит для таких задач.

Comment: А если мне нужен интерфейс для отображения активности и различных состояний, то как? Из активити запускать службу, а из службы обращаться к элементам активити?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы у вас продолжалось выполнение ваших операций при сворачивании приложения или что?

Comment: да, мне нужно, чтобы продолжались все операции при сворачивании до тех пор, пока я не закрою приложение.

Comment: Да, тогда точно нужен сервис. Ну и в активити брать данные для отображения из сервиса.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно использовать [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Неплохая статья на русском — [Service](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php)

**Service** работает без *UI* в фоне приложения (в отдельном потоке и, если нужно, даже процессе) и существует как раз для длительных задач, который делаются без участия пользователя.

**Service** имеет гораздо меньшую опасность быть закрытым из-за нехватки ресурсов. Но, даже если сервис закроется, он будет снова запущен, когда освободятся ресурсы (для этого существую специальные флаги).

Так же для **Service** может быть вызван метод [startForegroound()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), который практически исключит возможность закрытия сервиса при нехватки ресурсов.